# How to toggle className of more than 1 list elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component called NavMain.js and a child component called NavEventDate.js. I am passing some data from the parent component to the child comp using props.
When the child component is rendered I want only the first `<li>` element to have the `className="selected"`, then by clicking the other `<li>` elements I want only the one clicked to have the `className="selected"` and the other `<li>` elements to have the `className=""`. (toggled off)

This is a picture that explains how it is working right now
[image]
So if I am clicking on the `<li>` elements all remain with the `className="selected"` unless I am clicking it twice.

This is my code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-heisenberg-pg9x6?file=/NavMain.js

The logic from the parent component is not so important as the problem is in the child component. I included all the logic for better understanding of how I am passing the props.

Comment: your code sandbox is not working properly and it says `main.css` is missing. If you can provide I can check it out. Based on what you are saying. changing style won't enough. you will have to keep the state as well. to get the selected items.

Comment: Im working on your codeesandbox, im refactoring it, wait a moment, but there will be no css since the file doens't exist...

Comment: You can use an array for ['Sunday', 'Monday'...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your codsandbox, i've solved it by refactoring

Basically, you want to handle the selected item in your parent, and pass to your childs which one is selected. When you click on a child, you use the handleSelect function passed as props to tell the parent that you changed the selected index.

Then in your child you just pass a bool as props (isSelected) testing if the selected index is equal to the index of the item in the current instance of the .map

So only one child will get the true of this bool.

Then in your navevent date, you can refactor the way you conditionally add the selected class. Since you don't want to pass a class if it's empty you could just use this operator **&&**. Basically, if the isSelected is true it will apply the selected class, otherwise it won't apply anything.

I've removed the first condition beceause i didn't understand what you were trying to do, and left only the isSelected as reference.

NavMain

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import "./Main.css";
import NavEventDate from "./NavEventDate.js";

export default class NavMain extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentSelectedIndex: null,
      date: [
        {
          day: 0,
          month: 0,
          year: 0,
          dayName: ""
        },
        {
          day: 0,
          month: 0,
          year: 0,
          dayName: ""
        },
        {
          day: 0,
          month: 0,
          year: 0,
          dayName: ""
        },
        {
          day: 0,
          month: 0,
          year: 0,
          dayName: ""
        },
        {
          day: 0,
          month: 0,
          year: 0,
          dayName: ""
        }
      ]
    };
    this.GetOneDayFormat.bind(this);
    this.SetDate.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let startDate = new Date();
    this.SetDate(startDate);
    console.log(this.state.date);
  }

  SetDate(startDate) {
    let dates = this.state.date;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let currentDate = new Date();
      currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);
      dates[i].day = String(currentDate.getDate());
      dates[i].month = String(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
      dates[i].year = String(currentDate.getFullYear());
      dates[i].dayName = String(this.GetOneDayFormat(currentDate));
    }

    this.setState({
      date: dates
    });
  }

  GetOneDayFormat = (today) => {
    let dayNumber = today.getDay();
    let dayName = "";
    switch (dayNumber) {
      case 0:
        dayName = "Sunday".substring(0, 3);
        break;
      case 1:
        dayName = "Monday".substring(0, 3);
        break;
      case 2:
        dayName = "Tuesday".substring(0, 3);
        break;
      case 3:
        dayName = "Wednesday".substring(0, 3);
        break;
      case 4:
        dayName = "Thursday".substring(0, 3);
        break;
      case 5:
        dayName = "Friday".substring(0, 3);
        break;
      case 6:
        dayName = "Saturday".substring(0, 3);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return dayName;
  };

  handleSelect = (index) => {
    this.setState({ currentSelectedIndex: index });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <nav id="sectionNav" class="datepicker event">
        <div className="clearfix list-days">
          <h1>Events</h1>
          <ul className="mobile-off">
            {this.state.date.map((data, index) => (
              <NavEventDate
                dayData={data}
                index={index}
                isSelected={this.state.currentSelectedIndex === index}
                handleSelect={this.handleSelect}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

NavEventDate

```
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";
//import "./Main.css";

function NavEventDate({ dayData, handleSelect, index, isSelected }) {
  const dayToday = new Date();

  return (
    <li
      onClick={() => handleSelect(index)}
      className={isSelected && "selected"}
      data-date="20/11/2020"
    >
      <a href="#">
        {dayData.dayName}
        <h1>{dayData.day}</h1>
      </a>
    </li>
  );
}

export default NavEventDate;
```

As you see, i've added just a css property to turn the selected item bullet yellow, so you could see the result.

Tell me if you need further explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! everything works, except that I want to have the first item by default selected when the child component is rendered.

Comment: Then change the state default value to the index you want to be selected as default and everything is fine ;) Could you please validate the answer if it helped you solve your problem